# Incorrect xdpi and ydpi values for Some Motorola Devices

Tags: android

I am trying query xdpi and ydpi value of Motorola Droid2 global and Motorola Atrix to calculate screen width, These are the values i am getting

Atrix:
Resolution: 540*960
xdpi: 160
ydpi: 160
calculated screen width is coming to 6.1, whereas originial value is 4

Droid 2:
Resolution: 480*854
xdpi: 144
ydpi: 144
calculated screen widht is coming to 6.9, whereas original value is 4.

Same logic of width calculation works fine with Xoom, HTC, samusng phones and some other android devices. In those cases xdpi and ydpi reported are around 240

Are values 144 and 160 correct values?

If this is not the right approach any idea, how can we calculate screen width programatically?

Comment: have you found an answer for these questions?

Comment: They fixed these in later modules of the motorola devices

Comment: Just confirmed the Bionic has wrong reported densities: XDens: 368.060364 YDens: 365.225250 (literature reports ~256dpi) ... I'm trying to troubleshoot a layout sizing issue reported from a Razr, I think this is it.