# How reliable are real-world dimensions in Android views?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, kotlin

I'm working on an Android app with a specific requirement that items should be drawn to screen in real-world dimensions (e.g. "draw a solid 10x20mm rectangle").

There are two ways we can do this:

1. Use [`DisplayMetrics.xdpi`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html#xdpi) and [`DisplayMetrics.ydpi`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html#ydpi) in a `View` class to calculate dimensions based on exact physical pixels per inch of the screen (e.g. `val px = inches * context.resources.displayMetrics.xdpi`).
2. Use real-world dimensions in layout XML (e.g. `layout_width="20mm"`).

However, we're aware that [historically some devices have misreported their xdpi/ydpi values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6123287/incorrect-xdpi-and-ydpi-values-for-some-motorola-devices), making these techniques unreliable. Using `mm` in a layout XML file shows a warning in Android Studio:

> Avoid using "mm" as units (it does not work accurately on all devices): use dp instead

**My question is: how much of a problem is this on recent Android devices in 2019?**

The post [linked to above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6123287/incorrect-xdpi-and-ydpi-values-for-some-motorola-devices) is 8 years old. Is there a more up-to-date dataset across a range of current devices? We've tested it on a small selection of devices (Samsung, Google, OnePlus, Huawei, Motorola, Nokia) and it works on all except for a Nexus 4 running LineageOS. We can probably cope with some outlying use cases that don't work as long as most mass-market devices work properly.

Comment: How accurate must it be? I.e. how many % off reality is OK?

Comment: @Enselic That's a good question. In my experience it looks like these figures are either correct or very wrong (e.g. they report the much less accurate `dpi` value). On the devices we've tested on you can measure the rectangle with a ruler laid against the screen and they're exact. I'd say we need it to be accurate to the nearest millimetre, so very slight variations are not a problem.

Comment: There are tens of thousands of Android devices. If I were you, I would officially support only the devices you know have accurate measurements.